# Nestjs: `Incorrect date value: 'gdfg' for column 'createdAt' at row 1`

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Мне нужна ваша помощь. Я пытаюсь выполнять операции CRUD в nest.js. У меня проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь сделать запрос POST, я получаю ошибку 500 в Postman, и cli выдает ошибку:

> Incorrect date value: 'gdfg' for column 'createdAt' at row 1
> at Query.onResult (D:\todo-nest-project\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33)
> at Query.execute (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:36:14)
> at PoolConnection.handlePacket (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:488:32)
> at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:94:12)
> at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
> at Socket. (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:101:25)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
> at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)

В Postman ввожу следующие данные:

```
{  
  "title": "One",
  "description": "Two",
  "isTaskDone": false,
  "createdAt": "gdfg"
}
```

Файла `(D:\todo-nest-project\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33)` у меня в проекте даже нету...
Подскажите где у меня ошибка, как ее решить? Большое спасибо

TasksEntity

```
@Entity('tasks')
export class TasksEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment',{type: "int", comment: "Unique guess identifier",})
  id: number;

  @Column({type: "varchar"})
  title: string;

  @Column({type: "varchar"})
  description: string;

  @Column({type: "varchar"})
  createdAt: string;

  @Column({type: "boolean"})
  isTaskDone: boolean;
}
```

TasksModel

```
export interface TaskModel {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  createdAt: string;
  isTaskDone: boolean;
}
```

TasksService

```
export class TasksService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(TasksEntity) private tasksRepository: Repository<TasksEntity>) {}

  public getAllTasks() {
    return this.tasksRepository.find();
  }

  public getDifferentTask(id: number) {
    return this.tasksRepository.findOne({where: {id}});
  }

  public createNewTask(task: TaskModel) {
    return this.tasksRepository.save(task);
  }

  public updateExistsUser(id: number, task: TaskModel) {
    return this.tasksRepository.update(id, task);
  }

  public deleteExistsTask(id: number) {
    return this.tasksRepository.delete(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Похоже что `"createdAt": "gdfg"` - ожидается формат даты, судя по ошибке. Детальнее, надо смотреть в коде, в том месте, где ошибка возникает

Comment: да, но у меня нигде не написано, что ожидаеться формат даты

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно стек трейс на бэке, откуда ошибка приходит

Comment: @SwaD `Incorrect date value: 'gdfg' for column 'createdAt' at row 1
    at Query.onResult (D:\todo-nest-project\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33)
    at Query.execute (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:36:14)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:488:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:94:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\todo-nest-project\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)...`

Comment: Судя по трейсу, вы пытаетесь значения в БД запихать. Посмотрите, какой формат поля там

Comment: Извините, не понял вас. У меня тип string i varchar. Или я не тот метод использую - вместо `save`, нужно `create`?

Comment: У вас вызывается MySQL `driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33`, сохранение в БД. Ошибка идет оттуда. Смотрите строку 222 указанного файла

Comment: Мы можем перейти в чат? У меня даже этого файла нету...

Comment: У вас не хватает репутации для чата. Ваш трейс говорит об обратном. Он сообщает название файла, строку и позицию, откуда прилетела ошибка. Вот полный путь к файлу `D:\todo-nest-project\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts`. Вы точно все это писали или часть была скачена из просторов инета?

Comment: У меня в косноли нету ссылки на этот файл потому что среди файлов моего проекта нету этого файлу... Этот код писал я сам...

Comment: `D:\todo-nest-project` Это ваша папка?

Comment: да, это назва проекта

Comment: ¯\\(ツ)/¯ Я не знаю как может происходить ошибка в файле, которого нет, который что то делает в MySQL и возвращает оттуда ошибку.

Comment: https://github.com/Dmytrii9Cherniak/todo-nest-project, посмотрите пожалуста